# Why does my submit button fail to call php function?

Tags: php, dynamic-content

I have a very simple php site that and am attempting to make it a little more dynamic.  Previously, I required user to click on a link to open a new page containing several images together with some 'submit' buttons.  Pressing a button called a php file that saved some information in a text box.  This was working fine.  However, I have now made the content a little more dynamic so that the user chooses an item from a popupmenu to update content in the same page.  However, now the submit buttons produced dynamically do not seem to work.  I am quite new to web development generally so not sure why this should be the case.  Any help much appreciated.

This is the index.php file that populates the list box and sets up the page to dynamically manage the content.

'''php

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
        function showImages( imageDate ) {
            if ( imageDate == "") {
                document.getElementById("imageTable").innerHTML ="";
                return;
            } else {
                if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                } else {
                    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }

                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200 ) {
                        document.getElementById("imageTable").innerHTML = this.responseText;
                    }
                }
                xmlhttp.open("GET", "dispData.php?imageDate="+imageDate, true );
                xmlhttp.send();
            }
        }   
        </script>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Title</title>
        <meta name="language" content="en" />  
        <meta name="description" content="" />  
        <meta name="keywords" content="" /> 
    </head>
    <body>

    <?php

    $myDirectoryStr = "trialImages/";

    // open this directory 
    $myDirectory = opendir($myDirectoryStr);

    // get each entry
    while($entryName = readdir($myDirectory)) {
        $dirArray[] = $entryName;
    }

    // sort into date order
    sort( $dirArray );

    // close directory
    closedir($myDirectory);

    //  count elements in array
    $indexCount = count($dirArray);

    ?>      
        <?php
        // loop through the array of files and print them all in a list
        $cnt = 0;
        for($index=0; $index < $indexCount; $index++) {
            $extension = substr($dirArray[$index], -10);
            // start new row of table
            if ($extension == 'tempIm.png'){

                $dateStr[$cnt] = substr($dirArray[$index], 0, 8 );

                $cnt++;
            }
        }

        //  count elements in array
        $indexCount = count($dateStr);

        // find unique dates
        $dateStrUnique = array_values( array_unique( $dateStr, SORT_STRING ) );

        //  count elements in array
        $indexCount = count($dateStrUnique);

        echo '<form>';
        echo '<select name="dates" onchange="showImages(this.value)">';
        echo '<option value="">select date ...</option>';   

        for($index=0; $index < $indexCount; $index++) {
            echo '<option value="' . $dateStrUnique[$index]. '">' . $dateStrUnique[$index] . '</option>';   
        }

        echo '</select>';
        echo '</form>';

        ?>

        <br>
        <div id="imageTable"><b> image information will be displayed here ... </b></div>
</body>
</html>
```

'''

This is the dispData.php file that produces the dynamic content used to update the div tag and containing the submit buttons and images

'''php

```
<?php
    // recover some information
    $imageDateTarget = $_GET['imageDate'];

    // image directory
    $myDirectoryStr = "trialImages/";

    // open directory 
    $myDirectory = opendir($myDirectoryStr);

    // get each entry
    while($entryName = readdir($myDirectory)) {
        $dirArray[] = $entryName;
    }

    // sort into date order
    sort( $dirArray );

    // close directory
    closedir($myDirectory);

    //count elements in array
    $indexCount = count($dirArray);

    echo    '<table class="fixed">
            <col width="200px">
            <col width="200px">
            <col width="100px">';       

        // loop through the array of files and display them in table
        for($index=0; $index < $indexCount; $index++) {
            $extension = substr($dirArray[$index], -10);
            // start new row of table       
            if ($extension == 'tempIm.png'){ // input image place in first column

                // image date
                $imageDate = substr($dirArray[$index], 0, 8 );

                // if image date the same as selected date then display image
                if ( strcmp( $imageDateTarget, $imageDate ) == 0 ) {

                    echo '<tr>';
                    echo '<td>' . $dirArray[$index] . '</td>';
                    echo '</tr>';

                    echo '<tr>';
                    echo '<td height=400><img src="' . $myDirectoryStr . $dirArray[$index] . '" class="rotate90" " alt="Image" border=3 height=200 width=400></img></td>';

                    echo '<form action="writeNotes.php"  method="POST">';

                    //search for matching image notes if they exist and display
                    $indexImageNotes = array_search( $imageDate . 'notes.txt', $dirArray );
                    if ($indexImageNotes){
                        $notes = file_get_contents($myDirectoryStr . $imageDate . 'notes.txt');  // read contents into string
                        echo '<td><textarea name = "notes" rows = "26" cols="30">' . $notes . '</textarea></td>';
                    }
                    else {
                        echo '<td><textarea name = "notes" rows = "26" cols="30">add some comments here ...</textarea></td>';
                    }
                    echo '<td><input type = "submit"></input><input type = "hidden" name = "imageDate" value = "' . $myDirectoryStr . $imageDate . '"></input></form></td>';
                    echo '</tr>';
                }
            }   
        }
?>
```

'''

And this is the writeNotes.php function that saves the text notes and should be called when the submit buttons are pressed

'''php

```
<?php 
print_r("I am here");
$file = $_POST["imageDate"] . 'notes.txt';
$data = $_POST["notes"];
file_put_contents($file, $data);
?>
```

'''

Part of the problem is that I don't get any error messages, just a failure to execute the writeNotes.php function

Comment: Is your submit button wrapped in a form tag?

Comment: Put `print_r($_POST);die();` at the top of `writeNotes.php` file

Comment: Use `ìni_set("display_errors", true)` to show errors in production envs and `error_reporting(-1)` to report all errors.
Then you should see an error message.

Comment: Thanks for comments.  Yes, the submit button is wrapped in a form tag and was working fine when the content wasn't dynamically loaded.  It feels like there is some consequence of dynamic content and the operation of the submit button.

Comment: Hi Zain, I included the recommended lines in the writeNotes.php function to indicate if the function is ever called but to no avail.

Comment: Hi Code Spirit I have set up error logging via a php.ini file on the server but this doesn't record any problems.

Answer (score 0):

I think there must be some mistakes in my earlier code as I have attempted a further simplified version and this seems to work.  I simply populate a popupmenu below

'''php

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
        function showImages( imageDate ) {
            if ( imageDate == "") {
                document.getElementById("imageTable").innerHTML ="";
                return;
            } else {
                if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                } else {
                    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }

                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200 ) {
                        document.getElementById("imageTable").innerHTML = this.responseText;
                    }
                }
                xmlhttp.open("GET", "dispData.php?imageDate="+imageDate, true );
                xmlhttp.send();
            }
        }   
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <select name="dates" onchange="showImages(this.value)">
                <option value="">select date ...</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
            </select>
        </form>

        <br>
        <div id="imageTable"><b> information will be displayed here ... </b></div>
</body>
</html>
```

'''

And return the dynamic content here

'''php

```
<?php
    echo '<form action="writeNotes.php"  method="POST">
          <td><input type = "submit"></input><input type = "hidden" name = "imageDate" value = "a_value"></input></form></td>';
?>
```

'''

And the writeNotes.php function

'''php

```
<?php 
$file = $_POST["imageDate"];
print_r($file);
//header("Location: index.php"); //note there must be no output before using header
?>
```

'''

This seems to work without a problem.  Apologies for asking the earlier question and thanks again for comments.

Comment: you shouldn't use PHP to `echo` html tags. And btw. `<input>` doesn't have close tag

Comment: and put your `<script>` below html (at the end of the file) if possible.

Comment: thanks Kafus, I have been reading a little more about efficient use of server resources and not using php to serve any static content.  I hadn't thought about this before and the above would be an obvious example of poor practice.